# Run SDL Window (Centurion GUI lib) in other thread?

Tags: c++, user-interface, sdl

I want to run a window in another thread (ie not the main thread) using Centurion (which uses SDL).

Here is how i run the thread:

```
auto _THR_WIN_HWND_MAINLOOP = ([&HWND_instance]() {
            HWND_instance._mainloop_();
        });
        // starts the window thread.
        std::thread _thr(_THR_WIN_HWND_MAINLOOP);

        _thr.detach();
```

Then my `_mainloop_()` function:

```
const cen::sdl sdl;
            // main loop here.

            cen::window hwnd;
            cen::renderer renderer = hwnd.make_renderer();


            hwnd.show();


            cen::event_handler handler;
            while (__flag_open) {
                while (handler.poll()) {
                    if (handler.is<cen::quit_event>()) {
                        __flag_open = false;
                        break;  
                    }
                }
                renderer.clear_with(cen::colors::white);
                renderer.fill_rect(cen::frect{ 25.0, 500.0, 125.0, 75.0 });
                renderer.present();
            
            }
```

Just a note, the `cen::window` constructor calls `SDL_Init()`.

The problem is is that on the off chance i run my program, it closes after a second or so. if i JOIN the thread instead of detaching it the window stays open. However i need the window to run in the background as i have other code that must be run. Is there any way to have a background thread that fully handles the SDL window as if it was its own program?

NOTE: No errors are thrown, the window just closes after a second or so, on the off chance?!

Comment: As far as I know, the thread which creates the window also has to handle all of the events (polling). So your operating system (which one are you using?) might close the window, because it cannot send events to the correct thread.

Comment: im using Windows x64, and all of my functions to do with SDL and Centurion are inside the `_mainloop_` function, and i am handling the events in there as shown below so...

Comment: GUI code usually runs best on the main thread. Running GUI code on other threads is possible, but expect a bumpy ride.

Comment: Set breakpoint at loop break and see if your loop voluntarily terminates. What is `__flag_open` and how it is set? What your other thread doing?

Comment: @keltar `__flag_open` is a class member that is initially set to true, and in the code, I have shown is the only occurrence where it can be set to false. I have removed that piece of the code to see if it was the event system but it still closes on its own.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i was not labeling my `HWND_instance` class variable as `static`, and that variable held almost everything to do with SDL. So when it got destroyed, so did the SDL instances:

before:

```
_CE_WINDOW_HWND HWND_instance(s.get()); // create the instance.


        auto _THR_WIN_HWND_MAINLOOP = ([&]() {
            HWND_instance._mainloop_();
        });
        // starts the window thread.
        std::thread _thr(_THR_WIN_HWND_MAINLOOP);

        _thr.detach();
```

After:

```
static _CE_WINDOW_HWND HWND_instance(s.get()); // create the instance.


        auto _THR_WIN_HWND_MAINLOOP = ([&]() {
            HWND_instance._mainloop_();
        });
        // starts the window thread.
        std::thread _thr(_THR_WIN_HWND_MAINLOOP);

        _thr.detach();
```

As you can see, now the variable does not get destroyed after the function ends, preserving the lifetime of SDL and the class.